# python how to find the number of days in each month between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two date columns Start Date and End Date and I want to find the Year and number of days in each month between those two dates. I can find a year but no idea how to find the number of days in each month. Not sure if it is feasible to get this o/p.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

df = {'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
      'Item': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'StartDate': ['2019-12-10', '2019-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-05-10', '2019-03-10'],
        'EndDate': ['2019-12-30' ,'2019-12-31','2019-03-30','2019-11-30','2019-06-10']
        }
df = DataFrame(df,columns= ['Id', 'Item','StartDate','EndDate'])
```

Expected O/P:
[image]

Comment: Are the start date and end date guaranteed to be in the same year? If not, what should the output look like then?

Comment: yes, currently all the dates are 2019.

Comment: you tagged this with datetime, so I assume you are thinking of using that module? If you have 2 datetime.datetime objects, you can just subtract those datetime.datetime objects like `t0 = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 9)` and `t1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10)` then `t0 - t1` (or vice versa) then get a datetime.timedelta object, in this case `datetime.timedelta(60)`. You just then access the days as an int using its `.days` attribute.

Comment: sorry I didn't intend to use it. Edited the same.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with solution using `pd.date_range` and `resample`. You need convert both columns `StartDate` and `EndDate` to datetime dtype

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

def days_of_month(x):
    s = pd.date_range(*x, freq='D').to_series()
    return s.resample('M').count().rename(lambda x: x.month)

df1 = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].apply(days_of_month, axis=1).fillna(0)

Out[1036]:
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  21.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  31.0
2  31.0  28.0  30.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  22.0  30.0  31.0  31.0  30.0  31.0  30.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0  22.0  30.0  31.0  10.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Finally join back to original dataframe

```
df_final = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].join([df['StartDate'].dt.year.rename('Year'), df1])

Out[1042]:
   StartDate    EndDate  Year     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8  \
0 2019-12-10 2019-12-30  2019   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1 2019-12-01 2019-12-31  2019   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2 2019-01-01 2019-03-30  2019  31.0  28.0  30.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3 2019-05-10 2019-11-30  2019   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  22.0  30.0  31.0  31.0
4 2019-03-10 2019-06-10  2019   0.0   0.0  22.0  30.0  31.0  10.0   0.0   0.0

      9    10    11    12
0   0.0   0.0   0.0  21.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0  31.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3  30.0  31.0  30.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I tried the solution. This gives an error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. This could be because of multiple rows having the same dates!

Comment: That's interesting! 2 rows with same `StartDate` and `EndDate` are still fine. BTW, I rollback the old revision because `.dt` need datetime dtype. However, I don't think it will cause you `reindex error`. Where did you encounter error? are you able to create up-to `df1` ?

Comment: df1 = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].apply(days_of_month, axis=1).fillna(0) 
While creating df1 I am getting the error (ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis)

Comment: Could you narrow down your dataset to a sample which causes this error? I tried a few combinations of the posted sample. All of them work fine.

Comment: I just have some ideas on the error. Check your real dataset to see any `StartDate` and `EndDate` of each row spanning 2 years with overlapped months. it may cause reindex error.

Comment: L, you are correct there are few rows with such dates.

Comment: I guess in those cases you want to sum of duplicated months ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204000/discussion-between-aby-and-andy-l).

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I am at work and my company system disable chat :(. Just edit and put all updated info in the original question. I will try my best to help.

Comment: I posted a separate question 59274898 instead of updating. If you can pls take a look and help. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a solution in that question. Just a few minor changes from this solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can employ a combination of **vectorization with pandas and numpy** to achieve this as follows. The **custom function** is provided below, for ease of use. Since, it uses vectorization, it is supposed to be fairly fast.

Note: The **assumption** used here, based on the sample data:

- The date range is only for one year
- both start and end dates fall in the same year.

> If you have data from different years, you would need to apply this to each year's data there. Also, if start and end dates fall on different years, you will have to adapt this method for that. Since the problem presented here, does not state that requirement, I leave this implementation as a guide for anyone interested in its application to a multiyear-spanned dataset.

---

> If you would like to try out this solution in jupyter notebook environment, you can access it [here](https://github.com/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/answers/Q_59258248.ipynb) on github. It has a Google Colaboratory link as well. So, you could also, directly open it in [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/answers/Q_59258248.ipynb).

```py
# Updated DataFrame
df = process_dataframe(df) # custom function
display(df.head())
```

[image]

### Dummy Data and Custom Function

Tested with `pandas==0.25.3` and `numpy==0.17.4` in Google Colab Environment.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
from IPython.display import display

# Dummy Data
df = {'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
      'Item': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'StartDate': ['2019-12-10', '2019-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-05-10', '2019-03-10'],
        'EndDate': ['2019-12-30' ,'2019-12-31','2019-03-30','2019-11-30','2019-06-10']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Id', 'Item','StartDate','EndDate'])

# Function for Processing the DataFrame
def process_dataframe(df):
    """Returns the updated dataframe. """
    df.StartDate = pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate)
    df.EndDate = pd.to_datetime(df.EndDate)

    month_ends = pd.date_range(start='2019-01', freq='M', periods=12)    
    month_headers = month_ends.month_name().str.upper().str[:3].tolist()
    month_days = month_ends.day.to_numpy()
    month_nums = (np.arange(12) + 1)
    # Evaluate expressions to avoid multiple times evaluation
    start_date_month_num = df.StartDate.dt.month.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
    end_date_month_num = df.EndDate.dt.month.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)

    #start_month_days = pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate, format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(1) - df.StartDate
    # start_month_days.dt.days.to_numpy()
    # Number of days not in the end_month
    end_month_days_excluded = month_days[df.EndDate.dt.month.to_numpy() - 1] - df.EndDate.dt.day.to_numpy()

    # Determine the months that fall within the start and end dates (inclusive 
    # of start and end months) and then calculate the number of days in each 
    # month.

    # add all days for relevant months
    result = ((start_date_month_num <= month_nums) & \
            (end_date_month_num >= month_nums)).astype(int) \
            * month_days.reshape(1,-1) 
    # subtract number of days not in starting month
    result = result + \
            (-1) * (start_date_month_num == month_nums).astype(int) \
            * (df.StartDate.dt.day.to_numpy() - 1).reshape(-1,1) 
    # subtract number of days not in ending month            
    result = result + \
            (-1) * (end_date_month_num == month_nums).astype(int) \
            * end_month_days_excluded.reshape(-1,1) 

    return pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame(result, columns = month_headers), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

**Original DataFrame**:

```
# Original DataFrame
display(df.head())
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: @ABY Here's another way of doing it using vectorization. Please take a look at it and let me know how it went. Thank you.

Comment: getting the error for month_days calculation - " AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'. "

Comment: @ABY I have added a colab notebook implementation. It is working with the data you had posted in the question. It is available at the top of the answer. I am also leaving a link to it here. [Solution in Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/answers/Q_59258248.ipynb). Please take a look at this and see if you can figure out what is wrong with the data. Note that the assumption, as shown in your data is that the date range is only for one year and both start and end dates fall in the same year.

Comment: This was tested with `pandas==0.25.3` and `numpy==0.17.4` in Google Colab Environment. Didn't see the error you referred to.